# CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers is empty

Tags: java, serial-port, javax.comm

I am building a simple application that communicates through Serial Port using the Java Communication API javax.comm.

Here is some code in my java main method I wrote:

```
CommPortIdentifier cpi = null;
        Enumeration e = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) e.nextElement();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException n) {

            }
            System.out.println(cpi.getName());
        }
```

Enumeration e  is always empty even though I am connected to a COM 4 port when running this.

also, running this code:

```
portRead = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM8");
```

cause the throw of `NoSuchPortException`

I think I have done the installation part correctly and placed the properties file, the win32com.dll file in the right places.

Do you know what the problem could be?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that win32com.dll (comes with javax.com) is in the jre\bin directory.
Make sure javax.comm.properties (comes with javax.com) is in the jdk\lib directory.

Answer (score 7):

Remember always you need to add all the unzipped  files from javax.comm.zip to **jre**

win32com.dll  - jre/bin

comm.jar - jre/lib/ext

**java.comm.properties - jre/lib** (after adding this I found resolved  exception problem )

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (I installed x86 jdk )  and followed the steps

Your problem is that windows could'nt communicate the right PORT to your JAVA Program.

You have to copy the right files in the right location by following this link.

http://kishor15389.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-install-java-communications.html

Answer (score -1):

Find port  in which your device is working(Try power shell or hyper terminal to find all com ports   try  [link](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/08/31/writing-and-reading-info-from-serial-ports.aspx?Redirected=true))

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.