# Scan for available com port in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I want to scan available com port using Java. I used the following code using Comm library but its not working

```java
java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
int i = 0;
String[] r = new String[10];
while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()){
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
    r[i] = portIdentifier.getName();
    i++;
}
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(r));
```

`portEnum.hasMoreElements()` returns `false` every time.

I don't have the old fashioned `RS232` port on my computer I'm using a USB to `RS232` converter that I tested with putty.

I just want to scan available ports so I don't mind using others libraries.

**ANSWER**: 
I Used the code in comments bellows and its worked

```java
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
        for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have everything set up properly as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955530/commportidentifier-getportidentifiers-is-empty

Comment: Yes I Have all the files in the right directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which java version are you using? There might be problems with jdk 8.

Have you tried
https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

Example usage:

```
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
        for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For more examples visit https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_examples.wiki

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.